# Images are broken while migrating odoo v12 to v13

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I have migrated my odoo from v12 to v13 and now all my images are broken. I am getting an error in logs that
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/odoo/filestore/test_v13/15/1593fd001cb1bbb5b931bd2568c932fe92357d83'

I have checked in ir.attachment and I am not getting anything related to the above checksum

Even I am not able to upload the images from the frontend in this condition I am getting an error
**res.partner(< NewId origin=12392>,).image_128**

Can anyone please suggest how I can resolve this problem.

Comment: How did you migrated? Did you copy file-store also?

Comment: Yes, I have taken database backup with filestore and then I made some migrations changes in that database and then I have restored that database on my odoo v13 server